# Migrating to a new Machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, administration

I recently assembled a new workstation at my workplace. The current one is really old, (~3 years).

On the software front, the current system is running Ubuntu 14 and has a lots of bits and pieces that have been setup over the years. To make things simple, I figured cloning the two disks (250GB SSD's) that house the operating system would be a easy way to start. I used the tool `dd` for this job.

To test things out, I moved the older video card (nvidia) to new machine. So far the machine seems to boot and hang with these two messages:

```
mei_me 000:00:16.0: initialization failed
power_meter ACPI000D:00: Ignoring unsafe software powercap
```

Btw, the older machine was running a single cpu (i7) and the new one has two xeons.

Answer (score 0):

It was embarrassingly simple, the `fstab` file was referring to the partitions using uuid's. I fixed that and the machine booted fine.

There is still some room for tweaks though.